# How do i set the language on a fulltext index in mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table "article" with a column `fulltext_search` where I want to add a fulltext index

This part works

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`article` 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `ftindex` (`fulltext_search`) ;
;
```

but it will pluralize in english while searching with match against in natural language mode if i don't set the index language

It should be something like this

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`article` 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `ftindex` (`fulltext_search`) LANGUAGE 'it';
;
```

but i get a syntax error

Comment: i think that is not possible. a fulltext index is different from other indexes, why dp you want this`?

Comment: I think you're reading documentation for [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Despite having SQL in the name, it's an entirely different product.

Comment: English only.  For Chinese, see "N-gram" search.  What language(s) are you hoping to handle?

Comment: My SQL innodb, I guess I'm confusing with SQL server.

Comment: your add language is not supported as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The feature makes total sense. I may want to search for "foot" and find "feet". That cannot be reliably done if the system doesn't implement the English language rules. Whether a given vendor implements it or not is another question.